# SSAS relationship/granularity help

Tags: ssas

Hi all I have 2 fact tables with a measure group each, Production and Production Orders.

Production has production information at a lower granularity (at the component level) `productionorders`has information at a higher level (order level with header quantities etc.).

I have created a surrogate key link between the two tables on `productionorderid`. As soon as I add Prod ID (from `productiondetailsdim`) to the pivot table it blats out the actual qty (from prod order measure group) and I cannot combine the qty's from the two measure groups... How can I design the correct relationship between the two? please see my dim usage diagram.

Production Details is the dim that links the two fact tables... at the moment `DimProductionDetails` is in a fact relationship with Production.

I'm not sure what the relationship should be with Production Order (it is currently many to many) Thanks for your help!  If I combine the line level qty's with the header level i don't want the header quantities summed for every line (duplicates) i just want it summed at the order(header level) alongside the line qty's...

[image: SSAS relations]

Please see example data between the two tables
[image]

I have to be able to duplicate this behaviour below...

[image]

Comment: I still don't get it, where do the actuals come from? all I see in the details table are named estimate

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.  You can see in the screen shot the actual qty's are coming from the measures on the right.

Comment: @jhowe in excel yes, that is obvious, but how do they relate to the fact tables in your screenshots

Comment: prod orders is a measure group of factprodorders and production variance is a measure group off of production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating a named query in the DSV which contains the product key and productorder keys, linked these back to the two fact tables, created a new dim for production orders (so i had one for each fact table),  and created a new measure group off of the named query which acts as a bridge.  In dim usage I then setup regular relationships to the 2 dims for each fact table.  This seems to have fixed my issue!